# looking for strings starting with prefixes

Tags: python, parsing, dxf

Here is the part of DXF(I have trimmed some parts for clarity) file its about 5M

```
    \fCalibri|b1|i0|c00|p39;CB537
     73
         2
     44
    1.0
    1001
    ACAD
    1000
    MTEXTBEGIN
    1070

    1611.0
     30
    0.0
     40
    1.302083
     41
    0.0
     71
         1
     72
         1
      1
    \fCalibri|b1|i0|c00|p39;Line155
   //trim
     72
         1
      1
    \fCalibri|b0|i0|c00|p39;120

    \fCalibri|b1|i0|c00|p39;Bus459
```

I need search string started with prefix "CB" after I found it I need to find a next string starting with "Bus"
then print it out
In this file I need `CB537;BUS459`

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
\b(CB\d+)(.+?)\b(Bus\d+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yH9r6d/1/) and mind the `singline` mode.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you!

Firstly, let understand few things.

1. In python, you can open a file in `read`/`write`/`append` mode. You can't open a file in `read` mode and suddenly start writing! This causes file operational error.
2. For your case, you can do the following steps

   2.1  Open the file in `read` mode and read line by and collect the information required & then close the file.

   2.2 Re-open that file in `append` mode and write what you want

Below is some helper code for reference

```py
file_path = 'magic.txt' # Your input file name here
keys = ['CB', 'BUS']    # prefixes you want
values = [None, None]   # to store output lines

with open(file_path, 'r') as fp:
    i = 0
    for line in fp: # efficient for reading huge files
        if line.startswith(keys[i]):
            values[i] = line
            i += 1
        if i == len(keys):
            # found all required lines, no need read any further
            break

# Do you processing here
# ..
# ..

# How to append to file
append_data = ['Output this']

with open(file_path, 'a') as fp:
    fp.writelines(append_data)
```